# Как на сервере поймать input-данные и записать в файл?

Tags: input, android, java

Есть клиент, который отправляет через сокет данные. А сервер со своим кривым avialableом ловит не все. Как на сервере поймать input-данные и записать в файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читать правильно? `avialable` не кривой, просто он поэтому и называется `avialable` (доступно), а не `bytesAvialable`, что он только подсказывает, что какие-то данные можно прочитать. Кстати, в документации по java сказано, что даже если этот метод будет возвращать всегда 0, это все равно будет **корректно**!